# Eclipse CDT Indexer Behaving Erratically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I'm constantly battling the indexer in Eclipse CDT.Currently, I have code similar to the following and yes, this simple:

```
#include <Othernamespace/Bar>

class Foo : public Othernamespace::Bar
{
public:
    Foo(const Othernamespace::Zip& env);
};

Foo::Foo(const Othernamespace::Zip& env)
: Othernamespace::Bar(env)
{ }
```

There is no issue resolving the `<Othernamespace/Bar>` header file. 
There is no issue resolving `Othernamespace::Bar` as a parent class.
There is no issue resolving `Othernamsespace::Zip`.

However, in the `Foo` constrcutor, the chained call to `Othernamespace::Bar` gets flagged as an error. If I right click on the include, and examine the code, I can clearly see that the `Bar` constructor requires a `const Zip& argument`.

What's more: I have another project using the same framework with the same includes and Othernamespace::Bar is indexed just fine with no issues. Why, oh why can't I get this to index?

Again, I'm basically reusing code here, and in previous uses there wasn't an issue. I can open the included file from the editor and verify that my arguments are correct when invoking the parent constructor (and I have the indexer set to index files opened in the editor).

I have tried rebuilding the index. I have tried "freshening all files". I have tried upping the max limit for the index size from 64 to 128MB (not that I think I'm anywhere close to 64MB). None of that has made any difference.

I have also noticed that other calls to members of the inherited class are flagged as not found, which means any work I do on this class will be nothing but error flags. Again, I have verified that the included file (which is resolved) contains these method declarations. Still, nothing.

Other files in my project come and go from the index as well. They'll be fine one minute, but the next time i open them, it's all flagged as errors. I'll rebuild the index and it'll be fine for awhile, only for it to happen again later.

I feel like I'm spending more time battling the indexer than getting work done, and it's getting to be more than frustrating. Are there any suggestions out there for resolving these indexing issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on Eclipse and it's Indexer, but like you I've been fighting with it for quite some time now.  Your issue could be a bug in the Indexer, based off the info you've given.  If all the includes are indeed correct in the Project > Properties > c/c++ Build > Settings (I had an issue where I put the includes in the C area instead of the C++ area) then you could try deleting the ".index" folder from the "/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/yourProjectName" directory and then delete the project's PDOM file from "... /Eclipse_Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core".  Make sure eclipse is off during this whole process.  Then start it.  You'll need to redo your includes after this.  This worked for me so hope it helps you.  Good luck.